# Graduate program focusing on DevOps

Tags: masters, computer-science

I was asked the following question by someone who was interested in pursuing a career in devops, but wanted to learn things in a more formal environment such as a masters degree. Is there / Can anyone recommend any graduate program in the US that would help prepare said person for a career in DevOps? He already has a Bachelor in Computer Science in India.

Answer (score 1):

Schools in the US operate on a department basis. Almost all big research institutions will offer research work in the subject field. If your friend doesn't know anything about where the subject he is trying to study is thought, I think he is wasting his time on a graduate degree. Graduate study is research intensive work that requires more commitment on the student's side then it does on the professor's or school's side.

Comment: Computer Science departments focus on various areas of Computer Science such as Operating Systems, Graphics, Artificial Intelligence, etc. The problem is that DevOps is a relatively new focus and not enough schools teach the practical aspects of setting up and working in a data center. He is trying to find a department that would give him a theoretical knowledge of large scale systems, and some practical experience in working in an ops environment. Basically, he is looking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm like you stated DevOps is relatively new.  I have not seen DevOps being taught as a specific discipline; usually the DevOp skill set comes from the software engineering side of the fence in the US. Is he in the US or in India? See if any of these tickle his fancy:

http://unomaha.smartcatalogiq.com/en/2013-2014/Graduate-Catalog/Graduate-Degree-Programs-Certificates-Minors/Management-Information-Systems/Management-Information-Systems-MS

http://unomaha.smartcatalogiq.com/en/2013-2014/Graduate-Catalog/Graduate-Degree-Programs-Certificates-Minors/Computer-Science/Computer-Science-Concentrations

There's two versions of this degree, a professional one and a research one; the link below is of the research variety.  This institution also has campuses in London, Brussels, Dubai, Paris and Sydney along with a few other locations:

http://www.bu.edu/eng/admissions/grad/

The University of Illinois has a partnership with State Farm Insurance
http://www.ece.illinois.edu/students/grad/overview/ms.html

http://www.cdm.depaul.edu/academics/Pages/MastersDegrees.aspx

The University of Wisconsin has a partnership with Microsoft:

http://www.cs.wisc.edu/academic-programs/graduate-program